# How do I convert the json into a dataframe and ignore the top info?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, strava

I'm trying to convert some Strava activity data into a df to do some analysis.

The typical top of json looks like this in all files:

```
{
    "frame_type": "data_message",
    "name": "record",
    "header": {
        "local_mesg_num": 3,
        "time_offset": null,
        "is_developer_data": false
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "xx",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": xx,
            "raw_value": xx
        }
    ]
}
```

But there is a load of information above it which I am not sure how to filter out.

[image]

I'm trying to do
`df = pandas.json_normalize(data)`
but it returns this:

[image]

Essentially I want the table output to be:

| timestamp | position_lat | position_long | distance | time_from_course | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | row | data | more | columns too |  |

etc.

I am relatively new to this all so apologies for the noob question...

Comment: Please add an actual example of the JSON specifically with the "load of information above it" that you want ignored to your question — no one can help you otherwise.

Comment: Pasting JSON as text would let us copy and paste it into an IDE to work with....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish what you need by directly calling a pandas function. You may have to reformat your data beforehand. The [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) can help you manipulate your original data, treated as native Python lists and dicts, to define and populate a second "cleaned up" dictionary that you can then pass in `pandas.DataFrame`.

Starting from the string representation of the JSON file `s`, you can convert it into a list of dictionaries.

```
contents = json.loads(s)
```

Your `data3` variable seems to be in this format already. It is a list of dictionaries.

If I understand correctly, you want your dataframe columns to correspond to the 'name' fields, and the rows to be populated with the 'value' fields. `data3` contains many dictionaries, so each will correspond to a row. To develop working code for you, I created a silly example that I hope emulates what you have well.

```py
s = """
[
    {
    "frame_type": "data_message",
    "name": "record",
    "header": {
        "local_mesg_num": 3,
        "time_offset": null,
        "is_developer_data": false
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "x1",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 1,
            "raw_value": 1
        }, 
        {
            "name": "x2",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 2,
            "raw_value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "x3",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 3,
            "raw_value": 3
        }
    ]
},
   {
    "frame_type": "data_message",
    "name": "record",
    "header": {
        "local_mesg_num": 3,
        "time_offset": null,
        "is_developer_data": false
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "x1",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 1,
            "raw_value": 1
        }, 
        {
            "name": "x2",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 2,
            "raw_value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "x3",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 3,
            "raw_value": 3
        }
    ]
}
,   {
    "frame_type": "data_message",
    "name": "record",
    "header": {
        "local_mesg_num": 3,
        "time_offset": null,
        "is_developer_data": false
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "x1",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 1,
            "raw_value": 1
        }, 
        {
            "name": "x2",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 2,
            "raw_value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "x3",
            "value": "xx",
            "units": "xx",
            "def_num": 3,
            "raw_value": 3
        }
    ]
}]
 """
```

```py
data3 = json.loads(s)  # emulating your data3 variable
```

Instantiate an empty dict and start filling in the things you want. This dict will be passed to `pd.DataFrame()`.

```py
reformatted_data = {}  # instantiate
```

First, use the 1st dictionary to define the columns of the dataframe.

```py
for thing in data3[0]:
    for field in thing["fields"]:
        reformatted_data[field["name"]] = []  # instantiate columns
```

Then populate the rows

```py
for thing in data3:
    for field in thing["fields"]:
        reformatted_data[field["name"]].append(field["value"])
```

Finally, obtain the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(reformatted_data)
```

```
    x1  x2  x3
0   xx  xx  xx
1   xx  xx  xx
2   xx  xx  xx
```

Comment: This may or may not work, since it was a bit hard to understand the structure of your data and what you are trying to accomplish. If it doesn't work, please be more specific. Strip down your JSON example to the bare essentials, post it as text, and explain in more detail what needs to go where in the dataframe.